# How to return store admin variables in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

how simple would it be to do as in magento1

```
 Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/name')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/name');
```

And the equivalent for

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('path/goes/here')
```

is

```
$this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag('path/goes/here');
```

but you have to make sure that the _scopeConfig member exists.
if it doesn't inject it in the constructor. Like this:

```
protected $_scopeConfig;
public function __construct(
   ...,
   \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
   ....
){
    ....
    $this->_scopeConfig= $scopeConfig;
    ....
}
```

As a side node...I think the answers to all 3 questions you asked regarding magento2, should give you an idea on how to inject something you need in the controller and use it later.

Comment: i get a clearer idea indeed , very useful and clear replies as usual , thanks !!!